# internet with 2 network adapters

Tags: networking, router, dns, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a server with Windows 2012 r2 and have 2 network adapter NIC1 and NIC2

With NIC2 I have local net work and it work with IP4v :10.0.0.5 getway :10.0.0.2 with dhcp and dns server and clients start from 10.0.0.100 to 10.0.0.200 and all is working fine.

Now I use NIC1 to internet router and I have internet in server

How do I share this internet by server to all clients while keeping my local network configuration the same without changes?
thanks

Comment: Please clearly state what problem you are having and make your question clear.  Is dhcp running on the machine with 2 NICS?  You only list one IP address in your question, but only seem to give details of one of the NICs.

Comment: my clearly question is how share internet in server with all clients ??

Comment: Is there some reason that you want to have all of the traffic route thru your server?  You do not necessarily need to route the traffic through the server.  You would be better of coming out of your router into a switch and then have all of your devices also connect to the switch with Ethernet cables.  That way all of your devices will get DHCP from the router.  For your server, create a static dhcp lease on your router so that machine always gets the same IP address from your router.

Answer (score 0):

Ibrahim,

Here is an example of how you should configure your network.
[image]

Set the IP address of 10.0.0.5 statically on your server (I am assuming you have already done this).   As long as each computer is in the same subnet (I am guessing you are using 255.255.255.0, which is commonly called a /24 network), all devices should be able to communicate with each other.  A subnet of 255.255.255.0 means  you can have a total of 254 devices connected with IP addresses ranging from 10.0.0.1 to 10.0.0.254, regardless if the IP addresses you are using are statically assigned or handed out via DHCP.

If this situation does not work for you, please leave a comment and let me know and I will re-word my answer to your question.